# Hiding everything on the page until age verification popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So there is a particular page on the website I am building (just named the page file 19.html) for now where it asks if the user is over the age of 19 through a popup. Here is the 19.js file for that, which I have linked to on my 19.html page.

```
var yourAge = prompt("Please enter your age: ")
if (yourAge < 19)
   alert("Users under the age of 19 cannot access this page");

if (yourAge >= 19)
    alert("Enjoy!");
if (yourAge < 19)
    location.href = ("../html/index.html");
```

There is no content on the page yet so I just added a simple "Hello" text in the div class = "board" that I created on my 19.html page. However, I do not want the "Hello" text (and any other future content that I will be putting in the div for this page) appearing until the user successfully enters his age to access the page, and clicks OK after the "Enjoy!" popup. Can anyone help me how I will go about doing that? Will I have to implement jquery in some way? Please help, thank you.

the div board in my html file:

```
<div class="board">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You only have access to JS?

Comment: code the body's display:none, and the set it "block" after the prompt completes.

Comment: There are a lot of solutions that will work. However, you shouldn't send data that you don't want people to have access to. Even if the data is "hidden", if the users client received it, they can view it. Better to submit something to a backend service and have that service decide whether or not to send more data.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated based on comments*

*Assuming these CSS rule exists, the added sample will show the "Hello" text*

```
.board h1 {
  display: none;
}
.board.showme h1 {
  display: block;
}
```

A simple approach would be like this, using AJAX, though very easy to crack

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var yourAge = prompt("Please enter your age: ")
  
  if (yourAge < 19) {
    alert("Users under the age of 19 cannot access this page");
    // temp. commented out as not having a real link to 19.html
    //location.href = ("../html/index.html");
  }

  if (yourAge >= 19) {
    alert("Enjoy!");
    document.querySelector('.board').classList.add('showme');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {        
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "19.html", true);
    // temp. commented ou as not having a real link to 19.html
    //xhttp.send();
  }

})
```

```css
.board h1 {
  display: none;
}
.board.showme h1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="19.html">Goto page 19</a>
<div class="board">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

*Side note*

As @vastlysuperiorman suggested, you can of course simply call the 19.html file straight.

```
if (yourAge >= 19) {
    alert("Enjoy!");
    document.querySelector('.board').classList.add('showme');
    location.href = ("../html/19.html");
}
```

Comment: Technically, this answer does provide a solution to the question as asked. Similar to my comment above, I would point out the OP should be aware that a user could simply navigate to 19.html, instead of waiting for the XHR request to do it.

Comment: Hey LGSon, I tried your AJAX code but it doesn't solve the problem. When i click the link to the 19 page on my navigation bar, the text "Hello" is visible immediately. I want it hidden and only visible after the user has successfully gone through the pop up (being 19+) by clicking Ok to the "Enjoy!" pop up. Hope that clarified.

Comment: @JasonHyungchulKang My code does not show or hide any div/content, it shows how to access the 19.html file. If show/hide, you need to update your question with the html as well or else any suggestion will be a wild guess.

Comment: @JasonHyungchulKang Updated my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

To have something happen after an alert finishes alerting (when 'OK' is clicked), you can build a custom callback function. Here is your code with the addition of a callback:

```
var yourAge = prompt("Please enter your age: ");
if (yourAge < 19) {
   alert("Users under the age of 19 cannot access this page");
   location.href = ("../html/index.html");
}

if (yourAge >= 19) {
    function wishWell(amsg, callback){
        alert(amsg);
        if(typeof callback == "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }

    wishWell("Enjoy!", function(){
        location.href = ("19.html");
    });
}
```

As many users have mentioned, this is not a secure method to prevent access to your page since the javascript will be viewable by the user including all the links.

This is also not the best way to have a user interact with your site. Some browsers such as Chrome allow for popup alerts to be blocked via checkbox "Prevent this site from displaying additional popups." or something to that extent. If the user has checked the box, all your prompts will be ignored using previously entered data when they revisit the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would hide the content `div` and only display it if the user's answer >= 19. Something like the following would work:

19.html

```
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
// ...
</div>
```

19.js

```
var yourAge = prompt("Please enter your age: ")

if (yourAge >= 19) {
    alert("Enjoy!");
    document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
} else {
    alert("Users under the age of 19 cannot access this page");
    location.href = ("../html/index.html");
}
```

However, even though this works, it still relies on JavaScript being enabled. And since the content is already sent, one can easily open developer tools and change the style manually.